# External named Credential is not able to fetch in Apex code for Winter 24 Pre

Tags: apex, rest-api, oauth2, namedcredentials, client-id

1. Created the External Named credential with name Samsung Test [image]
2. Added the Principal [image]
3. Added the permission set [image]

However I am not able to fetch this named credential in Apex code.

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('callout:samsungtest');
req.setMethod('POST');
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
System.debug(res.getBody());
```

> System.CalloutException: The callout couldn't access the endpoint. You might not have the required permissions, or the named credential "samsungtest" might not exist.

Comment: Have you raised a support ticket?

Comment: Not yet. i would do it on Monday. It will be released in my sandbox by then.

Comment: Take a look at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/409484/external-named-credential-with-oauth-client-credentials-flow

Answer (score 1):

You have named your Named Credential "samsungtest" but in the Apex you are calling out to `samsungtest2`.

Comment: My bad. I edited it. It was my mistake. The problem is the same.

Comment: Do you have that permission set?

Comment: Yes. i have assigned to me - System admin user